# Using createTextNode() but I need to add HTML tags to it (JavaScript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, createtextnode

When I click an item in a table, I need it to add that item to a list and display that list.

Here's my code for adding/displaying the items in the list:

```
    var myList = document.getElementById('my-list');

    function addItemToList(id) {

        var entry = document.createElement('li');

        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));
        myList.appendChild(entry);

    };
```

This works great, but I also need to add a "delete" button to each item in the list.

But when I add `+ ' <a href="#">delete</a>'` to the `createTextNode()` parameter, it doesn't work. This is because, obviously, textNodes can only have plain text.

So how do I make this code work with the HTML tag? Is there any JS or Jquery method other than `createTextNode()` that will do the same thing, but allow HTML tags?

Comment: why you need `createTextNode` for an element which is delete button in your case. ? use `createElement("BUTTON")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any particular reasons you're using `createTextNode()` or avoiding jQuery selectors, but if it's simply because you're new to jQuery overall, than this code snippet has some updates with better practices and solves your problem. Hope it helps!

```js
var $myList = $('#my-list');

function addItemToList(id) {
  var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#">Delete</a>');
  $deleteLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove()
  })
  
  var $entry = $('<li>'+id+'</li>')
  $entry.append($deleteLink)

  $myList.append($entry);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my-list">
  
</ul>

<a href="#" onClick="addItemToList(1)">Add Item</a>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for also including the deleting function!

Answer (score 9):

With the specific scenario you mention, you would just set `innerHTML` of the `li`

```
entry.innerHTML = id + ' <a href="#">delete</a>'
```

Otherwise, either create the element like you did for the `li`, but using an `a` instead, and append it. Or just use `insertAdjacentHTML()` to append the whole thing

Creating the element

```
var entry = document.creatElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "#";
link.innerText = "delete";
entry.appendChild(link);
```

Using insertAdjacentHTML

```
entry.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',id + ' <a href="#">delete</a>');
```

Demo

```js
var id = "Some Text";
var list = document.querySelector("ul");
var entry = document.createElement("li");
entry.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `${id} <a href="#">delete</a>`);

list.appendChild(entry);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Also since you tagged jQuery, you can do the same thing as `insertAdjacentHTML` but by calling jQuery's `append()` method

```
$(entry).append( id + ' <a href="#">delete</a>' );
```

Comment: `${id}` is it jquery

Comment: @Mahi, no that is making use of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation) which among a few other things allows for expressions within the string

Answer (score 6):

One possibility would be:

```
function addItemToList(id) {

    var entry = document.createElement('li');

    entry.innerHTML = id + '<a href="#">delete</a>';
    myList.appendChild(entry);

};
```